# How do I create a randomly distributed boolean variable for a <breed> that will change in the model?

Tags: variables, boolean, netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I am writing a model with two breeds:
sexworkers and officers
where sexworkers possess a boolean variable that is randomly distributed at the setup, but then changes at the go according to the behavior of and interaction with officers. 
I use sexworkers-own [ trust? ]

in the preamble, but then I am not sure how to distribute y/n of the variable randomly across the sexworkers population. Really appreciate any input!

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're just wanting `sexworkers` to randomly choose between `true` and `false` for the `trust?` variable on setup. If that's right, then maybe `one-of` will do the trick for you- for an example, run this simple setup:

```
breed [ sexworkers sexworker ]
sexworkers-own [ trust? ]

to setup
  ca
  create-sexworkers 1000 [
    set trust? one-of [ true false ]
  ]
  print word "% Trusting: "  ( ( count sexworkers with [ trust? ] ) / 
    count sexworkers * 100 )
  reset-ticks
end
```

If you're looking for some kind of uneven distribution you can do simple ones using the `random` or `random-float` primitives. For example, if I want 25% of the `sexworkers` to start with `trust? = true`, I can do something like:

```
to setup-2
  ca
  create-sexworkers 1000 [
    ifelse random-float 1 < 0.25 [
      set trust? true 
    ] [
      set trust? false
    ]
  ]
  print word "% Trusting: "  ( ( count sexworkers with [ trust? ] ) / 
    count sexworkers * 100 )
  reset-ticks
end
```

For specific distributions, have a look at the various [random reporters](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/random-reporters.html)

For weighted randomness, have a look at the [`rnd` extension](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/rnd.html)

Comment: Thanks so much! I used one-of, but wasn't sure if this was distributing it randomly, or instead just 1/2 each. But it seems it is random?

Comment: @MiraFey - Yep, good instinct- it is random. Check out the [one-of dictionary entry](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/one-of.html) for the more details.

Comment: Thanks so much, that is great to know! This works well now! Still a lot left to code for the model, but at least the setup is as I want it now.

Comment: @MiraFey - Excellent, happy coding!